# Embedding ComboBoxes in a DataGridView in a row to allow filtering (like in Excel)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, row, embedding

I am implementing an application using VB.NET (Visual Studio 2017) and I would like to embed ComboBoxes in a row of a DataGridView (like filtering in Excel); data for the ComboBoxes does not come from a database, the ComboBoxes are pre-filled in a "sub".

Comboboxes are defined to be embedded in a DataGridView on a column-by-column basis (Column Type = DataGridView ComboBox Column), but not on a row-by-row basis. Does anyone know if this is possible and how? Thank you for the much appreciated help..

First I decided to use the first line of the DataGridView for the ComboBoxes and I "freezed" it by setting its frozen property to "TRUE".

Then I defined ComboBoxes programmatically (on runtime), named them and filled them in a "sub" with values...

Dim myCMBBox As New ComboBox()
myCMBBox .Name = "myCMBBox "

...then I inserted them Boy-by-box in the first row:

Call insert_CmbIntoDGV(myCMBBox , 1)

Private Sub insert_CmbIntoDGV(ByRef FilterCmb As ComboBox, ByVal theDGVCol As Integer)
FilterCmb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
FilterCmb.Visible = True
'
myDataGridView.Controls.Add(FilterCmb)
FilterCmb.Location = myDataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(theDGVCol, 0, True).Location
FilterCmb.Size = myDataGridView.Columns(theDGVCol).HeaderCell.Size
End Sub

The result was very promising (see screenshot) but then I noticed that the ComboBoxes don't follow the horizonal scrolling of the DataGridView - this means the ComboBoxes were nor really "embedded" in the dataGridView...

[Part of the DataGridView with some ComboBoxes on the first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CYeF.png)

Comment: [DataGridView AutoFilter -Excel Filtering in DataGridView](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/datagridview-autofilter-621f80f71b63)